Civi form attachments
we use civi 5.72.1 with WordPress 6.5.3, and we have a competition coming up where we'd like people to be able to upload documents like word or pdf.
Is there a way to do this, and is it possible to save these files in a way that would be easy for multiple judges to access?
(We previously used google forms, and the documents saved in an excel spreadsheet, which could be shared.)
I'd really appreciate advice - we've run this competition over a couple of years and we'd love to finesse the system with a proper civi integration.  I'm also not sure how to organise the competition in civi, whether to do this as a campaign, or event.
Cheers
